# Python Memory Leak with pyzmq and tonardo

Tags: python, tornado, zeromq, pyzmq

my application use pyzmq work with tornado, main work is just like a task center.
The memory will increase into 6G when task is busy, but when i stop task request and after all zmq task finished, the memory only reduce to 3.9g. i use gc.set_debug(DEBUG_LEAK) to check memory garbage and find many objects can't be released.such as

```
<cell at 0x7fa3b33389f0: weakproxy object at 0x7fa3d88aafc8>,
<cell at 0x7fa3b3338ec0: function object at 0x7fa3d0ac52a8>,
<cell at 0x7fa3b33382f0: function object at 0x7fa3d0ac5aa0>
```

Environment:
python:2.7.5

tornado:4.5.2

pyzmq:17.0.0

code as below:

```
loop = ZMQIOLoop()
loop.install()
context = zmq.Context()
zmq_publish = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
zmq_publish.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:%s" % "5555")
zmq_dispatch = context.socket(zmq.REP)
zmq_dispatch.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:%s" % "5556")
zmq_result = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
zmq_result.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:%s" % "5557")
receiver = ZMQStream(zmq_result)
receiver.on_recv(on_worker_data_in)
dispatch_stream = ZMQStream(zmq_dispatch)
dispatch_stream.on_recv(dispatch_recv)
web.Application([(r'/api/v1/sync/(cli|snmp|all)', 
    CommandApiHandler),], autoreload=False).listen(port)
try:
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```